# SpringBoot application in Tomcat server: PostgreSQL Driver Not Found

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using Spring boot application to develop Postgresql based application using Eclipse IDE(openjdk version 1.8.0_151)

I have configured gradle as follows:

```
compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.1.4'      
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
```

I am using Spring JdbcTemplate to access database. Everything works perfect in Eclipse IDE. I want to create a war file and deploy into Tomcat 9 server. But unfortunately, I got the following error message:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://server:5432/db_pm
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:619)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:684)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:716)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:726)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:776)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForList(JdbcTemplate.java:853)
    at com.kpaudel.pm.PasswordManagerDAO.getSimilarServices(PasswordManagerDAO.java:108)
    at com.kpaudel.pm.PasswordManagerDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$482fbdc8.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.kpaudel.pm.PasswordManagerDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8f3e1618.getSimilarServices(<generated>)
    at com.kpaudel.telegram.bots.PasswordManagerBot.onUpdateReceived(PasswordManagerBot.java:87)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1255)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:301)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://server:5432/db_pm
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:159)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

I have copied Postgresql driver (postgresql-42.1.4.jar) into $CATALINA_HOME/lib directory also, that also did not help.

Comment: Did you see any driver in project class path? For example, in maven project we see it in `lib` folder.

Comment: Yes, driver postgresql-42.1.4.jar is there in lib folder. I also copied this file into $CATALINA_HOME/lib directory also. Did not work though.